# Hazelcast automatically adds member then removes it

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

In my app I am using Hazelcast version 3.7.8 and I have 2 machines set as members.
Once deployed, the 2 members are joining the cluster, but also a 3rd member is automatically added which after a few seconds it's removed.

My conf:

```
@Bean("hazelcastInstanceTest")
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPort(0);
    config.getGroupConfig().setName(name).setPassword(password);

    JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();

    joinConfig.getMulticastConfig()
            .setEnabled(false);

    List<String> members = Arrays.asList("MEMBER1:5701","MEMBER2:5701");
    joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig()
            .setMembers(members)
            .setEnabled(true);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Log from the 1st vm (on the 2nd vm it's the same output):

```
SocketAcceptorThread: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8] Accepting socket connection from /MEMBER3:45566
TcpIpConnectionManager: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8] Established socket connection between /MEMBER1:5701 and /MEMBER3:45566
ClusterService: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8]

Members [3] {
        Member [MEMBER2]:5701 - member2_uuid
        Member [MEMBER1]:5701 - member1_uuid this
        Member [MEMBER3]:5701 - member3_uuid
}

TcpIpConnection: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8] Connection[id=3, /MEMBER1:5701->/MEMBER3:45566, endpoint=[MEMBER3]:5701, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Removing member [MEMBER3]:5701, uuid: member3_uuid, requested by: [MEMBER3]:5701
ClusterService: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8] Removing Member [MEMBER3]:5701 - member3_uuid
ClusterService: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8]

Members [2] {
        Member [MEMBER2]:5701 - member2_uuid
        Member [MEMBER1]:5701 - member1_uuid this
}

TransactionManagerService: [MEMBER1]:5701 [test] [3.7.8] Committing/rolling-back alive transactions of Member [MEMBER3]:5701 - member3_uuid, UUID: member3_uuid
```

This sequence of log is repeating each minute.
I don't understand how *MEMBER3* ends up being added to the members list?
How can I block it from joining?

I tried to change the ports, but it's the same.
Unfortunatelly I cannot change the version - it's a complicated process in this company.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my group config of which password was an empty String. Added some characters for the password and no other instance tries to join the cluster now.
`config.getGroupConfig().setName(name).setPassword(password);`

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the logs is the consequence of the fact that a minimum number of members in a Hazelcast cluster is 3. As you have configured only 2 members, Hazelcast adds 1 dummy member for you. But as it is obviously not alive - will be removed immediately. Hazelcast will try every minute if it's back...

Solution: configure at least 3 members or stop using a cluster.